# How to implement buttons inside a AG grid rows in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to implement a AG grid table with a name, type columns. I want to add one more column "edit" in the table, and allow users to edit&delete the rows from the table. It will look like this:

[image]

I get my data from the redux store, this is the way I implement data inside rows.

```
const members = useSelector(state => state.members) // Get current members 
const data = {
  columnDefs : [
{headerName: 'Name', field: 'name'}, 
{headerName: 'Type', field: 'type'},
{headerName: 'Edit', field: 'edit'}
],
  rowData: []
}

members.map((member) => {
  data.rowData.push({
    name:member.name,
    type:member.type,
    edit: '' // ?? What comes here so I can delete & edit by rows easily with buttons ?? 
  })
})

return ( 
    <div> 
    <div className="ag-theme-material">
        <AgGridReact columnDefs={data.columnDefs} rowData={data.rowData} />            
    </div>
</div>

)
```

I am new to react-redux, what would be the best implementation? Is it even okay for me to get data inside the table with map function like above? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Apporach 1: Use editing dialog

You can make the edit button open an editing dialog and dispatch the new change to the store after the user closes it:

- Create a custom cell renderer for the button and dialog. In this example, I'll use Material-UI's [`Dialog`](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs). You can choose whatever dialog library you want however.

```js
function ButtonActionRenderer(props) {
  // props is ICellRenererParams. See:
  // https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/component-cell-renderer/#cell-renderer-component-2
  const { id } = props.data;
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [memberPayload, setMemberPayload] = useState(props.data);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const onClose = () => setOpen(false);
  const onSave = () => {
    dispatch(memberAction.update(id, memberPayload);
    onClose();
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Edit</button>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)}>
        <DialogContent>
          <EditingForm value={memberPayload} onChange={setMemberPayload} />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={onSave} color="primary">
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={onClose} color="primary">
            Save
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
}
```

- Register that custom cell renderer in ag-grid

```js
<AgGridReact
  columnDefs={[...columnDefs,
  {
    headerName: "Action",
    field: "action",
    width: 100,
    cellRenderer: "ButtonActionRenderer"
  }]}
  frameworkComponents={{
    ButtonActionRenderer,
  }}
/>
```

#### Apporach 2: Use Ag-Grid [Cell Editor](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/component-cell-editor/#simple-cell-editor-example)

Make your table cells editable and dispatch new changes to the store every time the input changes.

```js
const MyEditor = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    // props is ICellEditorParams. See:
    // https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/component-cell-editor/#cell-editor-component-1
    const field = props.colDef.field;
    const member = useSelector(state => state.members.id);
    const value = member[field];
    const onChange = (e) => dispatch(memberAction.updateField(field, e.target.value));

    return (
      <input
        ref={refInput}
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        style={{width: "100%"}}
      />
    );
});
```

- Register the custom cell editor in ag-grid

```js
<AgGridReact
  columnDefs={[...columnDefs,
  {
    headerName: "Name",
    field: "name",
    width: 100,
    cellEditor: "MyEditor"
  }]}
  frameworkComponents={{
    MyEditor,
  }}
/>
```

### References

- [Cell renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/component-cell-renderer/)
- [Simple cell editor](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/component-cell-editor/#simple-cell-editor-example)